# PostMessage being undefined using Win32 API in a D program?

Tags: winapi, d

This is a sample piece of code showing the problem. I need to use the `PostMessage` function but i can't seem to get the symbol recognised. I've created a simple program to opening a win32 window which works fine but when i use either `PostMessage` or `UnregisterClass` they don't seem to be defined. I've check the D source and they are there but why does the compiler complain? I tried using the ascii and wide versions too.

```
import std.c.windows.windows;

extern(Windows):

void main(string[] Args)
{
    PostMessage(0, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    PostMessageA(0, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    PostMessageW(0, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
}
```

Output:

> Error: undefined identifier PostMessage
>   Error: undefined identifier PostMessageA
>   Error: undefined identifier PostMessageW

How can i use this function call in a D program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std.c.windows.windows` is very incomplete. Use the [WindowsApi bindings project](http://www.dsource.org/projects/bindings/wiki/WindowsApi), instead.

Comment: They do seem to be defined in `C:\d\dm\include\win32\WINUSER.h` though. :(

Comment: D doesn't read C header files. There's an utility to convert them, but it's easier to just use the bindings project.

Comment: They are also defined in `C:\d\dmd\windows\user32.lib`, `C:\d\dmd2\windows\user32.lib` and `C:\d\dm\lib\user32.lib`. I might just define them myself as i only need these few.

Comment: Those are import libraries. They indicate which DLL these functions are in.

Comment: The import libraries do not contain the functions' signatures. You need both pieces of the puzzle.